# PHP file_exists IF Syntax

Tags: php

I can't get this dynamic img working correctly using file_exists or file_get_contents.  I know I need to specify the full path in the if statement but I think my syntax is wrong?  What am I missing?

```
<img width="200" height="150" src="/virginia/images/
<?php 
 if (file_exists(."/virginia/images/".$row['MLS_NUMBER']."_1.jpg"))
       echo(rawurlencode($row['MLS_NUMBER'])).'_1.jpg';
     } else {
       echo "/no_photo.jpg";
     }
 ?>" alt="" align="left" vspace="3" hspace="3" />
```

Here is what I am replacing to allow for an image not being in a directory:

```
<img width="200" height="150" src="/viginina/images/<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['LS_NUMBER'])); ?>_1.jpg" align="left" vspace="3" hspace="3" />
```

Comment: remove the leading `.` in `."/virginia/images/".$row['MLS_NUMBER']."_1.jpg"`

Comment: -1: You don't specify what "correctly" is. Adding some actual detail to your question would help

Comment: I updated the question to reflect what I am replacing.  I assume what I did was correct.

Comment: Use `is_file` instead of `file_exists`. The last one will return true even if the path is a directory, not a file.

Comment: You also have unmatched curly braces

Comment: I actually suggest **not** using is_file() as the results are not consistent. See the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) which state "Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB." I have personally experienced unexpected results with the `is_file()` function and now avoid it in favor of `file_exists()`.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove leading dot
- Uset full path relative to root
- Use file_exists

> ```
> if (file_exists("/usr/local/nginx/yourhost/virginia/images/".$row['MLS_NUMBER']."_1.jpg"))
> {
>   echo(rawurlencode($row['MLS_NUMBER'])).'_1.jpg';
> }
> else 
> {
>   echo "/no_photo.jpg";
> }
> ```

Comment: Its a virtual directory.  PHP won't read beyond the web directory will it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 if (file_exists("/virginia/images/".$row['MLS_NUMBER']."_1.jpg"))
       echo(rawurlencode($row['MLS_NUMBER'])).'_1.jpg';
     } else {
       echo "/no_photo.jpg";
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an rogue period at the beginning of the file_exits path `."/virginia/images/"`
Then you either need to remove the curly bracket in front of the 'else' or add an opening curly bracket before the first 'echo' statement.

assuming the paths are the correct filesystem paths from the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You miss testing. If you can not get the code working dynamically, first try to let it work statically. If it works then, then will you know on what you have to focus.

I will first define the base directory for images on a central place. Not in the code, but in a included configuration file. In that file I simply put something like

```
define('imageDir','/virginia/images');
```

Then will I test if code with an image and src attribute works. 
If that is working, then will I try to abstract this process and create code which should resolve to a valid image. The output of that process will I show with a log or print statement. That url can be used in the browser to show the image. If that works, then is the creation of the code piece of cake.

I did not give you a thorough code example, because other people have done so and that is not imo the biggest problem. You have the proper code. All you need is the proper road to create the exact code you need.